# Using DirectXTK to save screenshots in Windows Store app (Metro)

Tags: visual-c++, windows-store-apps, directx, file-permissions, windows-store

I'm working on a C++ Windows Store DirectX app and I'm trying to save screenshots to disk every so often.

I am using the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/) (DirectXTK) and the function SaveDDSTextureToFile which returns an HRESULT.

The problem is that the returned HRESULT is always:

> E_ACCESSDENIED General access denied error.

I assume this is some permissions/capabilities thing (it being a windows store app) but I can't find what I need to ask for permission for to be able to save files to disk.

The DirectX ToolKit says it is for Windows store applications as well as desktop applications but I can't find any information on their codeplex either.

Does anyone know what I need to have permission to do for this to work?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to find out where the toolkit is trying to save the files.  package specific app-local directories are the only places where an app can write to without asking for permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a way to do it. Basically as MooseBoys says you cannot save to anywhere because the app is sandboxed.

You can however save to the TempState folder of your apps package in AppData, which is all I need because I'm using this feature for debugging.

So the line I call is:

```
DirectX::SaveWICTextureToFile(deviceContext, texture2D, GUID_ContainerFormatPng, L"C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PACKAGENAME\\TempState\\test.png");
```

And this works great.

Comment: Using a hard-coded path is of course a problem. You should use the Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder or Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder as your base. This is covered on the DirectX Tool Kit [Wiki](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ScreenGrab&referringTitle=DirectXTK)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Store apps are sandboxed and have fewer permissions than desktop apps, especially when it comes to file access.  By default, apps only have access to write to the [local storage directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx), which isn't easily accessible from the shell.  If you want to save to the Pictures or Documents library, you will need to specify this access in the package manifest.  Additionally, you will need to use the WinRT file APIs to write the DDS files.  To do this, use `SaveDDSTextureToMemory`, then write the resulting raw DDS data to the `StorageFile`.  Check out the [File access sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-575b7b71) for more info on the WinRT APIs involved in writing this data as a file.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense thanks, I'll report back if it works :)

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to find SaveDDSTextureToMemory() in DirectXTK, there is only SaveDDSTextureToFile() and SaveWICTextureToFile(). Whereabouts is it?